# PostgreSQL: data retrieval from a private (authentication-based) RESTful web API using a foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, authentication, foreign-data, web-service

In some cases, one want to feed or populate some [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database tables using data fetched from the web, e.g. through a RESTful API (serving JSON features).

I've recently discovered [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) and I'm not yet 100% used to them, but they seem to be a very interesting option to replace some custom Python scripts that retrieve data from the web, process it and use a Python data wrapper (i.e. [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/), or others) to populate some of my PostgreSQL database tables with that data.

After some research, I've successfully used the [`ogr_fdw`](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw) (see also [here](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/querying-spatial-data-with-postgis-and-ogr_fdw)) for fetching data from an [OGC API features](https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/) endpoint as well as the [`http`](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) extension for retrieving JSON data from a standard public API. Both those APIs are public, so they don't need any type of authentication.

I'm now naturally wondering if it's possible to build a view or populate a PostgreSQL table using a foreign data wrapper which retrieves data from a *private* RESTful API, i.e. which has an authentication procedure?

If yes, what kind of extension should I use and how? I couldn't find a tutorial or any detailed information at the moment.

The authentications I want to succeed with are the web based ones, i.e.: [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [API keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_key) or [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/).